# Change Bootstrap System message

Tags: msbuild, wix, bootstrapper

Created a bootstrapper which install few of the components. But if any on the component fails  under mentioned dialog is shown. Is their any way to change the shown system message text?

[image: Pre-req Installation error]

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrapper engine is located under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine. In this directory there is a folder for each language with the strings. For English look in en\setup.xml.